# Configure expect in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to implement rspec with `expect`. I tried this:

***RSpec:***

```
describe WechatRequestBuilder do

  let(:request_builder) { described_class.new(env: 'test_env') }   
  let(:trx_types)       { ['wechat'] }
  let(:trx_type)        { 'wechat' }
  let(:gateway)         { 'wechat' }
  let(:currency)        { 'CNY' }
  let(:base_params)     { request_builder.send(:base_params) }

  it_behaves_like 'request builder', true   

  context '#submit!' do

    it "sends test transactions" do     
      allow(request_builder).to receive(:process_trx).with(trx_types, gateway)  
      binding.pry

      request_builder.submit! 
      expect(request_builder.submit!).to receive(:process_trx).with(trx_types, gateway)
    end
  end
end
```

Request modifier:

```
class RequestModifier   
  def get_trx_type(request_body)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(request_body)
    doc.search("transaction_type").first.text
  end
end
```

I tried to find some object with binding.pry but without a luck:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::WechatRequestBuilder::Submit>)> request_builder
=> #<WechatRequestBuilder:0x007ffc1af4fd80 @env="test_env", @request_modifier=#<RequestModifier:0x007ffc1af4fd30>>
```

Can you give e some example based on the above code what should I configure as 'expect'? Currently I get:

```
(nil).process_trx(["wechat"], "wechat")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (["wechat"], "wechat")
           received: 0 times
```

Comment: That request modifier code looks... irrelevant.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you propose some other solution for `expect`?

Comment: I could, if it were clear what is it that you're trying to do.

Comment: Your expectation comes after you call submit, you need to reverse them or use the have_received pattern.